# How to get access to windows driver parameter

Tags: windows, driver

I have the usb to com converter, whith have own driver with graphic interface. I need to change some parameter by c# .net code. Driver allows changing only by window interface, I asked tech support. Is it possible to intersept command to hardware? View of drivers window.
Device : Moxa UPort 1250

Comment: maybe you need some pinvoke functions like [SetVolumeLabel](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.SetVolumeLabel). just search in that site.

Comment: Are you prepared to intercept IOCTLs and other relevant IRPs, reverse engineer the format, and then attempt to issue them yourself?

Comment: Nanofarad, yes! But how can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to reverse-engineer the driver, or reverse-engineer the program that communicates with the driver. Get out your kernel debugger and be prepared to read a lot of assembly language.